# Anonymous login unsupported on Parse Server (hosted by Azure)?

Tags: ios, swift, azure, parse-server

I recently migrated my iOS application from Parse to a Parse Server hosted on Azure. Everything appears to be working as expected except that I get this error when I use PFAnonymousUtils to log in an Anonymous user:

> ```
> [Error]: This authentication method is unsupported. (Code: 252, Version: 1.14.2)
> Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=252 "This authentication method is unsupported." 
> UserInfo={code=252, temporary=0, error=This authentication method is unsupported., 
> NSLocalizedDescription=This authentication method is unsupported.})
> ```

Here is the login sequence I am using in the AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWith Options):

```
        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = "my-awesome-app-id"
            $0.server = "https://awesomeapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/"
        }

        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
        let currentUser = PFUser.current()

        if currentUser == nil {
            PFAnonymousUtils.logIn {
                (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if error != nil || user == nil {
                    //See error above
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    user?.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that Anonymous Users are supported in Parse Server, which is why I find this error baffling. Is it possible that I need to change a configuration on my Parse Server on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to ensure `enableAnonymousUsers` is set to true in parse-server config.

https://github.com/mamaso/parse-server-azure-config/blob/master/index.js